# Make VSCode use global python config, not virtual environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'd like to use Visual Studio Code to edit a Python program.  To keep it portable, I'd like the Python program to be contained in a Python virtual environment.  To keep the venv small I'd like to only install those things that the Python program needs (and to specifically NOT install things that VSCode needs).

I told VSCode which venv to use by setting the  "python.pythonPath" variable in the settings.json file for my project (i.e., my Workspace Settings, not my User Settings).  This works fine in the sense that I can run the program / debug the program.

VSCode wants to use flake8 to do some linting, and I 100% support this - I greatly appreciate the Python linting that VSCode & flake8 do :)

*However, VSCode does this by installing the flake8 libraries into my program's virtual environment, NOT the computer-wide Python installation.*

**How can I set up VSCode to use the virtual environment for running & debugging the program, but install all the libraries it needs (flake8, rope, etc) into a different / system-wide Python directory?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the installation of `flake8` manually -- e.g. `python3 -m pip install --user flake8` outside of your venv -- and then manually set the [path to `flake8`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_flake8) in your personal `settings.json` file. That lets you run your code from your venv while installing flake8 for your user account (we don't recommend installing globally).

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what should the `"python.linting.flake8Path"` be set to?  I found one example that lists `c:\something\something\flake8.exe`, but pip installs a directory of Python files, not an .exe.  Setting it to `c:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\flake8` didn't seem to work, either.

Comment: @MikeTheTall So pip installs the library in site-packages, but it will install the CLI where appropriate on the platform. You should be  able to do `pip show flake8` and it will list every installed file along with the root directory. At the top of the file list will probably some location like `../../../bin/flake8.exe`. Combine that with the `Location` directory and that will give you the path.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  When I run pip show flake8 is lists out `License: MIT    
Location: c:\users\mike\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages   
Requires: mccabe, pyflakes, pycodestyle`.  There's no .exe listed anywhere.  (Side-question - I'm surprised that pip installs platform-specific executables.  I expected only source code.  I guess that works, but aren't there security concerns, etc?)

Comment: So I did the obvious thing and just searched my Python install directory for flake8.exe.  I found one, used that in the flake8Path config setting, and it's working great.  Thank you @brett-cannon for all your help!

Comment: In the case of these executables, they are just stubs that setuptools generates for entry points, so it's not quite the extent of a binary as you might think.

Answer (score 2):

When we create a virtual environment, a file called as `pyenv.cfg` is created in the virtual environment folder. Setting `include-system-site-packages = true` in this file results in the virtual environment using global site packages.

[image]