# How can I debug a python code in a virtual environment using VSCode?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, anaconda

**EDIT**

Using VSCode, I had an issue while debugging in a virtual environment that have different packages which are not installed in the `base` environment. After activating the environment with the command `activate my_env`, I can use the packages in the environment with usual python command as `python main.py`. But while debugging, I can't use the packages which are only installed in `my_env`. How can I debug a python code in a virtual environment using VSCode?

This is this the summary of the question. The rest has some specific info about my case.

**BEFORE EDIT**

I am trying to use `xmltodict` package with a simple code using visual studio code.

```
import xmltodict

with open('C:\\Users\\user\\foo.xml') as f:
    db_dict = xmltodict.parse(f.read())

print(db_dict)
```

I have a virtual environment named `my_env`, and I installed `xmltodict` package in it. When I activate the environment with `activate my_env`, this code works fine. But, when I try to use vscode **debug** option, it gives `No module named 'xmltodict'` error. Becuase vscode debug button opens new cmd and run the debugging command in it, I stopped debugging and typed `activate my_env`in that cmd and tried to debug again, but still it can't find the module. Also, I tried jupiter notebook in vscode, it also doesn't see the package.

I see that `import xmltodict` is underlined with red in vscode and it says `Unable to import 'xmltodict'`, but it works when I run it normally from cmd. This happens sometimes for other modules and I don't know why. I installed `xmltodict` module using `pip`, maybe it causes that.

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.30.1 with Anaconda Python 3.7.1 on Windows 10.

How can I debug a python code in a virtual environment using VSCode?
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48040625/6900838) question, but I don't think it is exactly what I want?

Comment: does this help: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments ?

Comment: Yes it is helpful. I tried a couple things from that documentation but I couldn't find the exact answer in it. Still, I can't debug my code.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Make sure the environment you want to use is [selected in the Python extension for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) by running the `Select Interpreter` command or via the status bar. Otherwise you can explicitly [set the Python interpreter to be used when debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python) via the `python` setting for your debug config.

Comment: Thanks. If we add `python.pythonPath` to `settings.json`, it works. But, I just want to add another way which is making the same thing. Use the `Python: Select Interpreter` command from the **Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)** and select the python interpreter that belongs to the new virtual environment. I tried this one at the beginning but I couldn't see a python interpreter for new environment in the selection list. **Restarting VSCode** fixed the situation fro me. After restart, I could see the python interpreter for the new environment in the selection list.

Comment: @Alperen glad it worked! Yes, the `Select Interpreter` command actually writes out the setting for you. And the newest release of the extension _should_ detect a new virtual environment in the directory, but we have to notice it which isn't necessarily immediate.

Comment: @Alperen I directly used your method and worked like a charm! Thanks ~

Comment: That explains alot. (sarcasm detected)

Comment: It is unclear in which file to put the python path key value store in your answer. I guess it should go in the project local settings.json.

Comment: for me in vscode v1.66.1 I had to add additional flag `"justMyCode": false` in my `./.vscode/launch.json` so it would work properly, after this flag, it started working and I was able to debug libraries also :)

Comment: explicitly setting the python interpreter: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Comment: Works with `code-server` as well.

Answer (score 7):

Use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and select the python interpreter that belongs to the new virtual environment.

If you are using a virtual env on `linux` on the drop down, select `env`>`bin`>`python` i.e `env/bin/python`

Answer (score 2):

I am using venv for creating virtualenv, and VS code to debug the code.

I found we don't have to create a launch.json file but add settings.json under {project}/.vscode/ folder.
My settings.json is as below:

```
{
"python.testing.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    ".",
    "-p",
    "test_*.py"
],
"python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
"python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
"python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/hhh/project/bin/python"
}
```

I can debug the project and run the unit test as well.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Menubar -> View -> Command Palette -> Python: Select Interpreter

Reference:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNaOE.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34701449)

Answer (score 0):

#### Two steps for the `venv` python debug

1. in the project local settings.json:

`"python.pythonPath":"venv/bin/python"`

2. On the left in the debug side panel: Click "create launch.json" below the blue "Run and Config" button
   A project local launch.json with python is created:

   `{ "name": "Python", "type": "python", "request": "launch", "program": "${file}", }`
3. Press F5 and shoot