# VS Code, Using venv but not able to use installed packages on venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using vscode, I have am using a venv and I have installed pygame in the venv. When I run pip list it shows up but when I try use it it gives an error saying that the package isnt installed. [C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf6yN.png)

Comment: Did you change your path option pointing to the virtual environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I debug a python code in a virtual environment using VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009081/how-can-i-debug-a-python-code-in-a-virtual-environment-using-vscode)