# VS code fails to load librairy from a python virtual env

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-venv, python-poetry

I have a python **virtual env** generated by [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) somewhere in `$HOME/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/pytorch-exploration-7_nwJ185-py3.8`. In this venv, I have [torch](https://pytorch.org/) installed as a library. `import` statements involving **torch** work while running my program with `poetry run`. To properly run the program, poetry needs

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
```

Despite that I set **VScode** to use this interpreter `$HOME/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/pytorch-exploration-7_nwJ185-py3.8/bin/python3.8`, I am still getting "*unresolved import 'torch'*" from VScode and I am unable to easily look at torch's objects definitions.

I read several hacks like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069740/7648881) but I'd rather find a way to load the **actual libraries of the venv** to avoid any version mismatch or side effects. Does VScode have the ability to load libraries from the venv based on the declared interpreter?

Comment: Try setting `"python.pythonPath"` to `"${env:HOME}/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/pytorch-exploration-7_nwJ185-py3.8/bin/python3.8"`.

Comment: Well, thing is: it is! It damned explicitly set in `.vscode/settings.json`. Turns out I have to restart VS code for changes to be taken into account. This will be the case every time I install new libraries. Any way to make it dynamic?